# How can i put this custom Linq query to view?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm kind of a newbie on Linq and could use some help.
I'm trying to set a custom Linq query to a MVC View but I can't really figure out how to?

Here is the code from my actionresult

from st in db.Stats

```
        orderby
            st.ID descending
        select new 
        {
            st.ID,
            st.Date,
            st.Created,
            st.Accepted,
            st.Ended,
            Totaltime =
                (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Created, st.Ended)/60) + ":" +
                 ("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Created, st.Ended)%60))
                     .Substring(
                         ("0" +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Created, st.Ended)%60))
                             .Length - 2, 2)),
            Ordertime =
                (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Accepted, st.Ended)/60) +
                 ":" +
                 ("0" +
                  SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Accepted, st.Ended)%60))
                     .Substring(
                         ("0" +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert(
                              (double) SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", st.Accepted, st.Ended)%60)).Length - 2, 2)),
            st.Message
```

I know that i should use viewmodel to get this right but i'm stuck on the Totaltime and Ordertime since they are created in the query.

Comment: "but I'm stuck": How are you stuck? What is it doing? What do you want it to do?

Comment: This is taking 2 time columns and datediff the time between them in a new column. both for totaltime and ordertime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `select new`, you can create a new concrete class and do `select new Example`:

```
public class Example
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can use LINQ to fetch a list of for example:

```
List<Example> data = (from x in events
                      group x by x.GetMessageFields() into grouping
                      let y = grouping.Select(x => x.GetFilename()).ToList()
                      select new Example
                      {
                          ID = grouping.Key,
                          Filename = y.First()
                      }).ToList();
```

If you have a model class, you can add a `List<Example>` to it now and use it:

```
model.ExamplesList = data;
```